# How to get multiple panels in one window - GTK+

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am looking to know what is the best practice to make a window which the content changes, but without changing the window. Something like using tabs, but with no tabs, controlled with buttons.

What widget should i use to archive what i need?

And if you don't mind the little off-topic, should it be drawn manually or with a GUI designer like glade?
It is meant to be used within python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use GTK 3.10, take a look at [`GtkStack`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html) and [`GtkStackSwitcher`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStackSwitcher.html). If not, use `GtkNotebook` and set the `show_tabs` property to `False`, then build your own buttons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you please provide any tip or guide on how to create childs? That documentation you gave it's for C, and this one ( http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/Stack.html ) gives a core dump after a try: http://pastebin.com/2G2r5J3K Whats wrong?

Comment: In line 7 you're trying to add the stack to itself, that won't work. Add it to another container.